# How use updatabe View in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am use EF6, the database-first, i.e. with the creation of an EDMX model. One table is used by previous developers to store different entities.  It's very wrong and it causes trouble.

The task is to leave the existing code as is and try to create different classes from this table. It seems to me the most logical to create several Views based on this table, each of which would represent the required class. You can write insert, update, delete to such View, since it refers to one table. The problem is that when you try to update an object created from the View, an error occurs.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: "Unable to update the EntitySet 'Sample' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

The entity understands that this is a view and, in general, cannot be updated.

So far, I see 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. Create Update, Insert, Delete function manually.
2. Manually configure the View data through the Fluent API (if possible).

I like the second option better. The problem is that the Fluent Api is more of a code-first approach. I can't get the `OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method to be called.

Is it possible to use EDMX model and Fluent Api together?

What other solutions can you suggest?

Comment: To answer your last question: not that is not possible. You will receive an exception when calling `OnModelCreating` in DB-First-Mode. I would just go for your first suggestion and create CUID functions

Comment: Maybe you can apply [TPH inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/inheritance/tph). depends on how the different types are distinguished in the table.